# Restore disappeared apps on SD linked with Link2SD?

Tags: link2sd

At some point Link2SD told me that it needed to regenerate the mount script, did it and offered a fast reboot option. This caused an endless boot loop which I escaped by

- checking the SD card (partitions: fat32, ext4, swap) in gparted on a PC. It turned out, it had some severe error which could be fixed. This is probably the reason for the need to regenerate the mount script. And by
- moving the folder `dalvik-cache` on the second partition temporarily to the PC, booting the Android device, shutting it down, moving `dalvik-cache` on the device again (otherwise it wouldn't break out of the boot loop)

After rebooting > 70 % of my apps were gone from the app menu. Their icons are still on the five main screens. The content of the SD card didn't change, so I believe there's high change to restore the apps by fixing Link2SD. I'd like to know how to do that.

I'm running a 4.0.4 no-name device.

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1208459
It worked for my HTC Desire HD with custom 2.3.5 Android